# Getting a mb_detect_encoding error when installing CSV Import Suite on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting the following error when installing the CSV Import Suite on my Wordpress / WooCommerce site,

*"CSV Import Suite requires the function mb_detect_encoding to import and export CSV files. Please ask your hosting provider to enable this function."*

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: Follow the suggestion given by the plugin. It's pretty clear: **Please ask your hosting provider to enable this function.**

Answer (score -1):

`mb_detect_encoding` is part of an optional extension for PHP. This extension is either not loaded or not installed on the server you are running this application.

http://php.net/manual/de/book.mbstring.php

On many linux systems it's called like `php-mbstring` or `php7.2-mstring` and so on.

If you are on a shared hoster you should as the error stated, contact your hoster to resolve this issue.

At least now you know what it needs.